# Place textAngular toolbar at bottom of the textEditor

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to add the textAngular toolbar at bottom of the texteditor-div. Right now it renders at the top.
I've been trying playin around with the css alot but with no sucess.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['textAngular']);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.htmlcontent  = "<h2>New Note...</h2>";

$scope.save =function() {

console.log( $scope.htmlcontent );

 $http.post("/Home/SaveWNote", { jsonData: $scope.htmlcontent });

}
});
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Testing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.2.3/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textAngular/1.2.0/textAngular-sanitize.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textAngular/1.2.0/textAngular.min.js'></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div text-angular ng-model="htmlcontent "></div>

  <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
  <br/>

Your htmlcontent <pre>{{htmlcontent}}</pre>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PREVIEW:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Wu1mc0v5bbuoLkvvDb9V?p=preview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the attribute `ta-target-toolbars` on the `text-angular` directive to have it register with an alternate toolbar:

```
<div text-angular ta-target-toolbars="toolbar" ng-model="htmlcontent"></div>
<div text-angular-toolbar class="toolbar" name="toolbar"></div>
```

Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/B2NU8RpUlSrKVFAlpOU2?p=preview

The relevant lines of code involcing `ta-target-toolbars` from textAngular are available here: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/blob/64d31658186bb9bb54c07f7c719d73a472d60b11/src/textAngular.js#L642-L656

Comment: that seems much better solution then mine :) +1

Comment: Is there any way to add checkboxes to the toolbar so I can use it the same way as the other listItems, like <ol> and <ul>?

Comment: By default checkboxes aren't allowed through the sanitizer - there's quite a few issues about working with plugins in the textAngular repo.

Answer (score 0):

you can play a bit with **css** to move toolbar under text area

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/Wu1mc0v5bbuoLkvvDb9V?p=preview

```
.ta-editor {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.editor-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 470px;
}
.ta-toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```